Font styling not captures with exporting html element to pngs
I am trying to export an html element (a div containing mostly an svg). There are no extra styles being applied (classes, etc) to the element.
The html element looks like this

But the saved png looks like 
Here are the different code snippets I have tried which all produce the same result
html2canvas:
const canvas = await html2canvas(el, { useCORS: true, copyStyles: true });
const image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
...

saveSvgAsPng
saveSvgAsPng.svgAsPngUri(
`filename.png`,{ scale: 1, encoderOptions: 1, excludeCss: true }).then(url => {
...
})

html-to-image
toPng(element).then((url) => {
...
}

Any advice or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

please include html/svg code to your quesiton, have you try to set the default font-family?
